# How to AngularJS ng-disabled directive works in Boostrap-select (Silvio Moreto)?

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-select

Does AngularJS 1.0.7 ng-disabled directive work with Silvio Moreto boostrap-select plugin?

I have this code:

```
disableLicenseType={{disableLicenseType}}
<select bs-select  name="licenseType" class="show-tick" data-width="320px" ng-model="boat.licenseType.id" ng-options="licenseType.id as (licenseType.name | translate) for licenseType in licenseTypes" ng-required="control || !createBoatPoliciesForm.licenseType.$pristine" ng-disabled="disableLicenseType">
    <option value="">{{'REQUIRED_LICENSE_PLACEHOLDER' | translate}}</option>
</select>
```

If disableLicenseType variable is initiallized to true, the it´s disabled, and if it´s first initiallized to false then is not disabled. However, after first time, when I change disableLicenseType value, I can see (inspecting with Google Tools) the disabled attribute is included or removed, however the select component does not change dinamically anymore.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know you must refresh your select controls after the value of the expression inside "ng-disabled" is changed. I did it this way and it worked. Whenever `disableLicenseType` is changed you can call, for example:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```

This command line is written in JQuery and calls the `selectpicker()` function for every element that has the "selectpicker" class. I don't know exactly why you are using this `bs-select` element instead of `class="selectpicker"`, but I believe you got the point.

Hope it helps.